# Merge rows with same username in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have data origination from Active Directory in a flat file that i need to export to SQL server using SSIS. My challenge is that I want to do all the operations in SSIS and have the data that is exported into the database as the final output. My flat file has several rows bearing the same username that need to be combined into one row, and then concatenating the data in one column as in my illustration below:

```
    Username        Office       LocationID    Dept
    --------        ----------   ----------    -----
1.  btan            HQ              01         Acct
2.  cvill           South           04         HR
3.  cvill           North           02         HR
4.  btan            East            03         Acct
5.  cvill           West            05         HR
6.  lkays           HQ              01         Legal
```

My output should be as follows and it should all be done using SSIS:

```
    Username        LocationID      Dept
    --------        ----------      -----
1.  btan            01, 03          Acct
2.  cvill           04, 02, 05      HR
6.  lkays           01              Legal
```

Any help will be very much appreciate.

Comment: Do you want to hear that you really, *really* don't want to have a delimited list stored in a column?

Comment: Check out https://www.google.com/search?q=string+aggregation+tsql but @billinkc is right - this is useful for reporting/presentation only. In DB it should all be done via relationship.

Comment: You can always get a comma delimited list of LocationID but this is a very poor databse model

Answer (score 1):

I support the prior suggestions that this is a bad data model, and I also support the SQL (non SSIS) solution. However if you must follow this path despite our warnings, take a look at the SSIS Pivot operator. You'll need to concatenate the resulting columns into one column.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you a comma delimited list of the IDs

```
SELECT Username, STUFF(IDList, 1,2,'') AS LocationID, Dept
FROM TableName T OUTER APPLY 
                            (
                            SELECT ', ' + LocationID  [text()]
                            FROM TableName
                            WHERE UserName = T.UserName
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) T2(IDList)
```

Comment: "My output should be as follows and it should all be done using SSIS"

Comment: Try the code in ExecuteSql task and I hope it will give you the output as you have shown in your question.